# Check if a dataframe element are all specific elements

Tags: python, pandas

I want to check if a dataframe contains all specific elements.
The psuedocode code:

```
if (df.iloc[i, 0:6] == 65535):
```

the idea is to check if column i row 0~6 (7 elements) are all 65535

how to implement it correctly?

Comment: Good idea to produce an MRE - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html), here `i` is index and `:6` is for selecting first `6` columns, if `df` is `DataFrame`:

```
if (df.iloc[i, :6] == 65535).all():
```

If `i` is column and `df` is `DataFrame` need:

```
if (df.iloc[:6, i] == 65535).all():
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the sum of matched rows you can use `sum()`

```
sum(df['ColumnName'].iloc[0:6] == 65535)
```

or you can get dataframe of rows matched your condition by using operator inside dataframe then apply `.iloc`

```
df[df['ColumnName'] == 65535].iloc[0:6]
```